# Let $g(x):= \int_a^x f(t)(x-t)dt$ for all $x$. How can one prove $g \in C^2 [a,b])$ with $g'' = f$?

Tags: integration, analysis, proof-writing

Let $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous and

$$g(x):= \int_a^x f(t)(x-t)dt$$ for all $x \in [a,b]$

Then it follows that $g \in C^2 [a,b])$ with $g'' = f$

Can someone prove that? I don't know why our book uses statements like these without proving them (even though they are probably true)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that $f$ is continuous. Then:

$$g(x)=x\int_a^x f(t)dt-\int_a^x tf(t)dt.$$

By the FTC and the product rule we derive

$$g'(x)=\int_a^x f(t)dt+xf(x)-xf(x)=\int_a^x f(t)dt.$$

Again by the FTC we get

$$g''=f.$$

Answer (score 1):

You need some condition on $f$. Here is a proof assuming that $f$ is continuous.

$g(x)=x\int_a^{x}f(t)dt-\int_a^{x}tf(t)dt$. Hence $g$ is differentiable and $ g'(x)=\int_a^{x}f(t)dt+xf(x)-xf(x)=\int_a^{x}f(t)dt$. It follow that $g'$ is differentiable and $g''(x)=f(x0$/

Answer (score 1):

Just note that $g(x) = x \int_a^x f(t) dt - \int_a^x t f(t) dt$ and thus, if $f$ has enough regularity,

$$
g'(x) = \int_a^x f(t) dt + x f(x) - xf(x)
$$

and

$$
g''(x) = f(x)
$$